# How to compile for csharp using angular-gettext?

Tags: c#, angular-gettext, grunt-angular-gettext

How to generate translation.cs file using the angular-gettext?

I am looking at https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools/pull/117 link it says it has support for csharp and and according to its main site (https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools) this tool is used for angular-gettext build.

I tried to google but I can't find much information on this. Anyone has tried to use this translation for csharp?